# Switch from pie to column and show labels

Tags: highcharts

I use buttons to switch the chart type from pie to column and back. Pie is the default. When I switched to column, no categories are shown.
[Image: Pie is the default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfdhx.png)

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Gebifa/vLrx47a6/1/

I aleady tried to set x-axis categories but only got Highcharts Error 18 - The requested axis does not exist. Do anybody have an idea how to show the labels? Thanks in advance.

```
exporting: {
            buttons: {
                contextButton: {
                    symbol: 'url(../../img/chartexport.png)'
                },
                barButton: {
                    x: -30,
                    _titleKey: 'barChart',
                    onclick: function () {
                        $.each(this.series,function(i,serie){
                            serie.update({
                                type:'column',
                                tooltip: {
                                    positioner: function () {
                                        return { x: 0, y: 0 };
                                    },
                                    pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b><br/>',
                                    shared: true
                                }
                            });
                        });
                    },
                    symbol: 'url(../../img/chartButtonBar.png)'
                },
                pieButton: {
                    x: -60,
                    _titleKey: 'pieChart',
                    onclick: function () {
                        $.each(this.series,function(i,serie){
                            serie.update({
                                type:'pie',
                                tooltip: {
                                    positioner: function () {
                                        return { x: 0, y: 0 };
                                    },
                                    pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.percentage:.2f}%</b><br/>',
                                    shared: true
                                }
                            });
                        });
                    },
                    symbol: 'url(../../img/chartButtonPie.png)'
                }
            },
```

Comment: Would you provide a fiddle?

Comment: Try to add dataLabels:{enabled:true} in your column series

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help you switching between two charts. Please provide fiddle if it does not fix the issue.

```
$('#Pie').click(function () {
    chart.inverted = true;
    chart.xAxis[0].update({}, false);
    chart.yAxis[0].update({}, false);
    chart.series[0].update({
        type: 'pie'
    });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wvymmy80/

I think your xAxis configuration has a little issue, title is not required in xAxis configuration.Please try replacing below code.

```
xAxis: {
      categories: ["20-29 years", "30-39 years", "40-49 years", "50-59 years", "60-69 years", ],
      enabled: false,
      text: '',
      style: {
        color: '#656565'
      },
    tickmarkPlacement: 'between',
    labels: {
      style: {
        color: '#656565'
      },
      rotation: 0
    },
    crosshair: true
  },
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xxLochh6/

Comment: Thanks, but it unfortunately didn't work for me. See the added fiddle with the code.

Comment: Yes! That did it! Thanks a lot! Stupid brackets... :)